# Play a wave file in linux

Tags: linux, audio

What is the **most portable way** to play a wave file in Linux?  I'd like this to succeed even if the user doesn't have particularly nice sound libraries installed (assume libc is installed and the user has sound configured, but nothing else).

Preferably, the method I use to blocks until the sound finishes playing and also avoids the overhead of launching a whole separate utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, there's not really a Linux sound API. There's ALSA and OSSv4 for hardware access, but if you use either API directly, you will likely be fighting a mixing daemon, such as PulseAudio, for access to the sound device.

You may be best off using something like [libao](http://www.xiph.org/ao/) or [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/).

Comment: Ended up doing an external call to aplay since ALSA was most available.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I would use `aplay`, which is part of the `ALSA` system itself.

```
$aplay a.wav
```

Links: [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplay) [(aplay man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay)

Since PusleAudio is built over ALSA, it will work on PulseAudio systems, too.

Answer (score 1):

cat mywav.wav > /dev/dsp

so i guess write to that file with a wav file ?

see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100905161536/http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/multilinux/excerpt/ch14-05.htm)

Comment: Does it work on modern linux..? With ALSA (and no DSP emulation) and PulseAudio running on top...? BTW, link no longer working.

Comment: @elcuco archive.org had a safe copy of the broken link. i updated the post with a working link. (8 years later but some of still use oss https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103746/11592)